# VBA Arrays: adding elements based on conditions

Tags: arrays, loops, excel, vba

I would like to collect the results of a loop in an array. Ideally, I would keep the results of the first loop and compare it against the results of the second loop. If the results of the second loop are better, then I want to keep the second, compare it against the third and so on. Any ideas on how this can be done? Here's an excerpt of what I have so far:

```
For Each ccell In pcrange
If ccell.Cells.Value = 0 Then
    For Each agecell In agerange
    If agecell.Cells.Value < 0.5 And agecell.Offset(0, 5).Value > 1 Then
    tmpyr = agecell.Offset(0, 1)
    srchyr = ccell.Offset(0, -6)
    tmpval = agecell.Offset(0, 2)
    tmpdiff = Abs(tmpyr - srchyr)
    arrindx = arrindx + 1

    End If

    tmparray = Array(tmpdiff, tmpval) 'need redim to hold more than 2 values? why are subsequent elements empty?
    ReDim Preserve tmparray(2 * arrindx - 1)
   'minarr = IIf(tmparray(2) > tmparray(0), tmparray(1), tmparray(3)); want to extract corresponding tmpval from array onto sheet if tmpdiff is the min of the entire loop; change to store better result each time
    Next 
End If
Next
```

Comment: Yes, you need to re-dim to hold more than 2 values (or add n empty values inside your Array(tmpdiff, tmpval) bit). You mention subsequent values being empty, where are you populating them?

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance, what is your end goal or goals? Is it to have the min of `tmpdiff`?

Comment: Hi Nick, I get a value for tmpdiff and tmpval when the agecell loop runs and meets the If conditions. Each time I get a tmpdiff and tmpval, I can't get tmparray to store the previous results for comparison- I thought redim preserve would help, but it doesn't hold more than 2 elements at a time.

Comment: End goal is to populate a column in Excel where ccells have a zero value, using the best tmpval I can find (with best being defined as the tmpval that corresponds to the smallest tmpdiff). I'm looking for some asset values in certain years and where I don't have them, I need to look for next closest as a proxy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Defining your `tmparray` should be like so:

```
tmparray(UBound(tmparray, 1)) = Array(tmpdiff, tmpval) 'add values to last place
ReDim Preserve tmparray(UBound(tmparry, 1) + 1) 'add another place to the array
```

And finding the new min should be if placed after the `ReDim`:

```
If UBound(tmparray, 1) <= 2 then 
    minarr = tmpval
ElseIf tmparray(UBound(tmparray, 1) - 1, 0) < tmparray(UBound(tmparray, 1) - 2, 0) then 
    minarr = tmparray(UBound(tmparray, 1) - 1, 1)
end if
```